# How to replace comments

Tags: java, replace, character

I am creating an application for different devices (phones,tablet,tv box) that takes a text box with user input (a few sentences) and sends it to a server. There are about five text boxes with user input. I was going to combine all of the boxes input into a long string, separated by commas.

In doing that I know that I need to convert the commas (to ascii, hex,??). I am using a `stringtokenizer` for commas on the server to separate.

I am going to store the user input in a database on the server (and will leave the converted commas in there??)

1. Is there a better way of sending the input from the five input boxes?
2. What is the proper way to replace any commas a user may have entered into the textbox?

Comment: Use XML or JSON and use a library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON or XML do send the data to the server, that way you won't have to worry about the user input containing commas. There are plenty of libraries around to serialize and deserialize JSON and XML.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JSON to transport the data to the server. In java a nice library to serialize/deserialize JSON is GSON (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you get the text from the textbox and you have is String, you can use this with the encodings you need:

http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/java.nio.charset/ConvertChar.html

But have in mind that the native Character set of Java is Unicode, which can be used to represent any typographies and charactes.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your inputs to only accept characters and digits and avoid the issue OR
run "awk '{sub(/\,/,"\,");print}' to replace all , with escaped characters OR
store the strings in a file, send the file, read the file.
lots of other options really

Comment: You're suggesting using awk to do string replacement in Java?? What's wrong with [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) ?

Comment: nothing, i just didn't see java in the title and was not sure if it was java or c. so i gave solutions that would work for either, my bad